# How do I give text an offset path in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, path, stroke

Okay, I am just trying out the offset path effect for a custom font.
I followed this tutorial - 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yU2wDdLNTdE
I tried doing the same, typed a word and expanded it,then put a stroke to it and finally offset path.I got the desired effect- the expanded version of my base letter,without expanding the red stroke proportionally.
[image: First offset path effect]

I tried to repeat the effect, as told in the tutorial,but by applying offset path again I get this-
[image: Second offset path effect]
However this was not my desired effect.All this has done is increased the fill for the inner 'o'.
I want the stroke to be retained for the blue path. In other words, I want multiple 'o's beneath the previous 'o'. Each bigger than the previous, but the stroke should remain- As shown in the tutorial.
How do I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that the 'o' you are trying to give an effect is two separate paths, probably in a group. Effects like offset will not work properly, indeed. You will want to select all the o's paths and then make them into a `Compound Path`: <kbd>Object > Compound Path > Make</kbd> or <kbd>right click > Make Compound Path</kbd>.

Besides, this effect is more easily achievable using the `Appearance` panel:

1. Type your text. If you want part of the letters to have the effect, type them as a separate object;
2. Be sure the object is selected;
3. Open the `Apperance` panel, <kbd>Window > Appearance</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>;
4. In the panel, select the `Characters` object and choose <kbd>Add New Fill</kbd>, either through the panel options or the filled square icon in the lower right: 
   [image: add new fill button in Illustrator CS6]
5. With that fill selected, give it a different colour and choose <kbd>Effect > Path > Offset Path</kbd>. Use `Preview` to fiddle with the offset value;
6. In the `Appearance` panel, drag the new fill below the `characters`. The Appearance panel works just like a layers panel.
7. Repeat with different colours and different offset values to create a multi-stroke effect.

Be sure during the whole process that your object stays selected, or it will not pick up the changes you make in the Appearance panel.

Comment: Ok , this worked pretty good ! I got my desired effect !
http://i.imgur.com/bQKSPos.png